# MySQL - DbProviderFactory.CreateCommandBuilder returns null

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, ravendb

I have been having issues with RavenDB 3.5 SQL Replication to MySQL server. I am using Windows 10, RavenDB 3.5 and MySQL 8.0.12. 
I have tried going back to basics, no SSL, barebones. I installed MySQL server, 8.0.12 connectors and `.Net` connectors. I then created a test schema, table and user that has all roles and privileges.

I can successfully test the connection to my SQL through RavenDB SQL Replication, however when i try to start SQL replication I always get a NullReferenceException below:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Raven.Database.Bundles.SqlReplication.RelationalDatabaseWriter.Dispose()
>   at
>   Raven.Database.Bundles.SqlReplication.SqlReplicationTask.ReplicateChangesToDestination(SqlReplicationConfig
>   cfg, ICollection`1 docs, Int32& countOfReplicatedItems)

I pulled down the source code and debugged it.

With example code [image: here] it appears that the ProviderFactory has an issue with MySQL, where it has this error inside the ProviderFactory

> '((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory)providerFactory).MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException'

This in turns means that the commandbuilder is null and the commandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(x) causes the NullReferenceException
as can be seen [image: here]

I am new to MySQL, I have done the same steps on 3 different machines, with the same error each time. It kinda feels like a MySQL/Environment issue, like some setting I have missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [MySQL bug 88660](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88660): `CreateDataAdapter` and `CreateCommandBuilder` are not implemented and both return `null`.

You'll have to wait for Oracle to release a fixed version, or switch to [MySqlConnector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/), which is API-compatible but doesn't have this bug.

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately its RavenDB 3.5 code base so we cannot switch to MySqlConnector. Apologies i am new to MySQL, but does this mean I can leave the MySQL server at the latest version (18.0.2) and just install the Net connector at at-least version 6.10.4? I have tried to install 6.10.8 but i still get the same error.

Comment: @G-Mac Sorry, I misread the bug report. It was _reported_ in 6.10.4, not fixed in 6.10.4. Since the status is still "Verified", I think it hasn't been fixed yet. I don't think there's a version of `MySql.Data` you can install that has the fix.

Comment: No worries, I tested with the previous GA Net Connectors. I can confirm that it works with 6.9.12. I'm not sure what the implications are using such a old version with latest Server but it appears to be working at a basic level.
Thank you so much for the help!